# Pynput. Ввод текста после нажатия на клавишу

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

Использую библиотеку pynput. Нужно, чтобы после нажатия определенного сочетания клавиш, пользователь мог ввести любой текст.

Вот код:

```
import sys

from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('\x11'):
        path_to_file = input()
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        listener.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Проблема в том, что в консоли после команды input() появляются какие-то левые символы. И эти же символы потом появляются в переменной path_to_file. Как их убрать?